# How to autoresize UIImageView (subview) and it's image with aspect ratio?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, autoresizingmask

I have a UIView (container view) which contains a UIImageView. When I adjust the the container view's frame (by gesture or programming), I want to autoresize the UIImageView's frame (and the image size with aspect ratio).

How should I set the autoresizingMask for those view, and the contentMode?